# Rendering whole chart into 3d instead of only bars

Tags: javascript, highcharts, 3d

I am trying to make bar chart 3d. What I managed to do so far is render only fragment of it.
This is from what I started

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: "container",
        type: "bar",
        
    },
    title: {
        useHTML: true,
        x: -10,
        y: 8,
        text: '<span class="chart-title"> Grouped categories <span class="chart-href"> <a href="http://www.blacklabel.pl/highcharts" target="_blank"> Black Label </a> </span> <span class="chart-subtitle">plugin by </span></span>'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{
            name: "Fruit",
            categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
        }, {
            name: "Vegetable",
            categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
        }, {
            name: "Fish",
            categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
        }]
    }
});
```

and this is the phase on the begging
[image]

After that I added the options3d object into chart object as following

```
options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 10,
        beta: 20,
        depth: 10,
        viewDistance: 50
    }
```

And result was good but only fragmental like this
[image]

And what I was aiming for ( please forgive my "photoshop skills" ) was this
[image]

So basically I am aiming for that table where is Fruit, Veggie and Fish to also be 3d same as rest of the chart. Anyone have an idea how to accomplish this ?
fiddle of chart without 3d
https://jsfiddle.net/a1rowqxn/
fiddle of chart with 3d
https://jsfiddle.net/ajx728Le/

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is not supported.

Comment: I was hoping that you were wrong but then I read Black Label on your profile and it broke my heart :) Thank you for replay Wojciech so much ! Have a great day !

Comment: Sorry that I disappointed you, I hope you will find the better solution;) Have a nice day too!